# Manually create PageSpeed urls for thumbnailing or resizing ajax-loaded images

Tags: php, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

It is possible to force PageSpeed to generate an ajax-loaded image at a smaller sizes using a manually written pagespeed resource url as follows:

**Original image url:**

> http://www.modpagespeed.com/images/Puzzle.jpg

**100x100 thumbnail:** *(thumbnail is not generated until first reload)*

> http://www.modpagespeed.com/images/100x100xPuzzle.jpg.pagespeed.ic.0.jpg

This works fine, however the thumbnail will not stay in the cache because it does not have a valid PageSpeed hash at the end of the url(I'm using `0` as the hash in the example above.

Is it possible to generate a valid hash using php or otherwise, which we can use to enable caching for this resource? How does `mod_pagespeed` generate the hashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a PageSpeed representative on Google Groups:

> Sorry, the only way to generate a valid hash is for PageSpeed to generate 
>   the optimized image link itself.  The main problem is that PageSpeed may not 
>   optimize the image completely on the first request, so if it responded 
>   to `myImage.jpg?compress=1&size=100x100` with longcache headers then it 
>   could poison caches with unoptimized resources.

It's a real shame because using this technique would be a quick and simple way to create a powerful, manually controllable image caching system.